# Using or condition in Xpath Attributes

Tags: xml, selenium, xpath

I have two different web pages and two different anchor tags
First one is
`<a href="#" data-titlex ="some title" class="class_name"/>`
and the other one is `<a href="#" data-titley ="some title" class="different_class_name"/>`.

I want to fetch the title of this anchor tag using selenium.
I am aware that I can use or between classes

```
//*[@class= 'different_class_name' or @class='class_name']
```

But I am not able to figure how to do the same for fetching data attributes (data-titlex or data-titley).

Comment: In that case better to use try..catch block or if..else block. Which language binding are you using with selenium?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one if you want predicate for 2 attribute with different names but the same values:

```
//a[@*[.='some title']]
```

or

```
//a[@*[starts-with(name(), 'data-title') and .='some title']]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to retrieve the value of attributes with either attribute name:

```
//a/@*[name() = 'data-titlex' or name() = 'data-titley']
```

The `@*` returns all attributes of each `a`.  The predicate filters for those attributes with exactly those names.